# Rails 3: How to get an array of all people "name"s?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`Person` model has a `name` field.

I would like to get an array of all people names.

If several people have the same name, I would like it to appear only once in the array.

I built the array this way:

```
Person.all.map{ |p| p.name }.uniq
```

Is there a better/more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: You *could* write a scope too

Comment: Shorthand: Person.all.map(&:name).uniq

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution is good enough for small data sets, but it would be inefficient for large data sets because your query retrieves all Person records from the database before it sorts them within your application code.

It's better to let the database do the heavy lifting with large amounts of data, so a faster, more performant approach would be to let the database filter distinct records first:

```
Person.select('distinct name').collect { |p| p.name }
```

Answer (score 3):

Offload work to the database whenever possible. Plus, use sym.to_proc to make the statement more concise for collect:

Person.select('distinct name').collect(&:name)